# Mapping over a custom function

Tags: r

I am getting stuck trying to incorporate the "pages" element here, along with the "type" - the pages element changes but the type remains constant.

The current code I have maps over the tickers and downloads the data into a list format, however it only uses the default number of pages, how can I map over the tickers as well as the pages?

Adding company_filings(pages, type) doesn´t work.

```
library(edgarWebR)

tickers <- c("63908", "793952")
count <- 100
pages <- 1:4
type = "10-K"

custom_company_filings <- function(compfilings){
  company_filings(compfilings)
}

x <- Map(custom_company_filings, tickers)
```

Edit:

What I am trying to achieve is to do something like:

```
for(tick in tickers){
   for(i in pages){
     company_filings("get company filings")
   }
}
```

So for each ticker I Will collect pages 1,2,3,4 of the `company_filing() function` - which comes from the `edgarWebr` package.

The `custom_company_filing()` function was my attempt at trying to solve the problem but when I posted here I removed all my attempts. For instance one attempt was:

```
custom_company_filings <- function(compfilings, pages){
  company_filings(compfilings, pages)
}

x <- Map(custom_company_filings(page = pages), tickers)
```

Comment: Where is the part where you supply the `pages`? Also, I don't see `count` and `type` being used in your function.

Comment: I have been playing around with different methods and I must of left them out. Currently the `custom_company_filing` does exactly the same as `company_filing` because I dont define anything in the `custom_company_filing` function.

Comment: So is your question how to map over your custom function, or how to map over `tickers` and `pages` at the same time for `company_filings`? The former would imply we have to use a custom function. The latter means we can use any other methods.

Comment: I added a small edit to explain myself a little better

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We can use a nested `lapply`:

```
library(edgarWebR)

tickers <- c("63908", "793952")
count <- 100
pages <- 1:4
type <- "10-K"

lapply(tickers, function(x){
  lapply(pages, function(y){
    company_filings(x, type = type, count = count, page = y)    
  })
})
```

Or with `purrr`:

```
library(purrr)

pmap(expand.grid(tickers, pages), ~company_filings(..1, type = type, count = count, page = ..2))
```

Comment: Thanks! I am getting an error on both of them. Should the `lapply` end with `})
})`? - I still get `Error in is.url(url) : length(url) == 1 is not TRUE ` and when I run the `pmap` function I get `Error in strsplit(URL, "") : non-character argument`.